# Installing Folly (c++ library) gives an error via vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, folly, vcpkg

I am trying to build `folly`  library which is a c++ library and tried to install it via `vcpkg`.

It downloaded all the dependencies and installed the dependent boost libraries as well.

But it gives an error for in the last step which is installing the folly.

I have used the following command:

> .\vcpkg.exe install folly:x64-windows

It has giving the following error:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:56 (message):
Command failed: ninja;-v
Working Directory: D:/C++Examples/Vcpkg/buildtrees/folly/x64-windows-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
See logs for more information:
  D:\C++Examples\Vcpkg\buildtrees\folly\config-x64-windows-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
   scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:237    (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
   ports/folly/portfile.cmake:57 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
   scripts/ports.cmake:72 (include)


Error: Building package folly:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
```

Here is the log file level details of the issue:

```
CMake Error at CMake/FollyFunctions.cmake:81 (if):
if given arguments:

"D:/C++Examples/Vcpkg/buildtrees/folly/src/8.05.14.00-e96738be27/folly/Benchmark.cpp" "MATCHES" "^D:/C++Examples/Vcpkg/buildtrees/folly/src/8.05.14.00-e96738be27/folly/build/"

Regular expression
"^D:/C++Examples/Vcpkg/buildtrees/folly/src/8.05.14.00-e96738be27/folly/build/"
cannot compile
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:101 (REMOVE_MATCHES_FROM_LISTS)
```

Do you have any idea how can i handle this issue?

Comment: Looks like the project's `CMakeLists.txt` expect path to not contain regular-expression-specific characters, but your path do: "+" has special meaning for regular expression. Try to use another path, without "+" character in it.

Comment: You saved a life :) Could you please provide comment as an answer so I will close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression

```
^D:/C++Examples/Vcpkg/buildtrees/folly/src/8.05.14.00-e96738be27/folly/build/
```

is invalid, because "+" character has special meaning for regular expressions, and "++" combination is meaningless(incorrect).

Looks like the project's `CMakeLists.txt` expects path to not contain regular-expression-specific characters.

Try to use another path for build the project, without "+" character in it.